# Request received always is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, redux, redux-form

I'm working with react, redux-form and laravel.
I have created a form to be able to insert notes in the database but when I show the `Request` in laravel an empty array always appears.
I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      notes: [],
    };

    this.submitToServer = this.submitToServer.bind(this)
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => json.results)
        .then(notes => this.setState({ notes }))
        .catch(console.log)
  }

  async submitToServer(data) {
    let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    let responseJSON = await response.json()
    return responseJSON
  }

  submit({ title, content }) {
    this.submitToServer({ title, content })
      .then(res => this.setState(prevState => ({
        notes: [...prevState.notes, {
          id: prevState.notes.pop().id + 1,
          title: title,
          content: content
        }]
      })))
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.notes.length > 0) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Notas</h1>
          <Paper>
            <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.submit)}>
              <Field name="title" label="Title" component={renderField} type="text" />
              <Field name="content" label='Content' component={renderField} type="text" />
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </Paper>
          ))}
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return <p>Cargando notas...</p>
    }
  }
}
```

In laravel at the moment I'm just returning the Request to show what it contains.

```
public function storeNote(Request $request) {
        return $request;
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing `this.props.handleSubmit`, by writing `<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.submit)}>` you are most likely invoking `this.props.handleSubmit` directly on render. Does it work if you write `onSubmit={() => this.props.handleSubmit(this.submit)}` instead?

Comment: Can you also include the code for the `handleSubmit` prop?

Comment: the fact that you have host:port in the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000` suggests this may be a cross origin request. Is the page itself served by the exact same server, i.e. ip address `127.0.0.1` on port `8000`? Do you see any errors/warnings in the developer tools console? In the developer tools network tab, do you see the correct response?

Comment: the method handleSubmit it's not implements, I call onSubmit

Comment: In the developer tools network tab not appears errors

Comment: Your code says `onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.submit)}` in the render method. Is that a copy/paste error? You don't seem to store the `title` and `content` anywhere in state. [Maybe you have to do something like this?](https://codesandbox.io/s/1zzkn6krx4)